# nextjs 13, 14 App Directory language without i18n - internalization

Tags: javascript, next.js, internationalization, next.js13, i18next

Question: Is there a way to do multi-language without i18n since it's a 2 pages website...

The context

The root layout has the language detection:

1- Using a context     that record french if french or else is english.

`<script async dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html:`(function () {
function setTheme(newTheme) {
window.__theme = newTheme;
window.__onThemeChange(newTheme);
}
// this will be overwritten in our React component
window.__onThemeChange = function () {};

```
              // this will be triggered by our React component
              window.__setPreferredTheme = function (newTheme) {
                setTheme(newTheme);
                try {
                  localStorage.setItem("lang", JSON.stringify(window.__theme));
                } catch (err) {}
              };

              // detect system theme and monitor for changes
              var darkQuery = navigator.languages ? navigator.languages[0] : (navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage)
              darkQuery = darkQuery.split('-')[0];

              var preferredTheme;
              // try to get saved theme
              try {
                preferredTheme = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("lang"));
              } catch (err) {}  
              // initialize preferredTheme
              setTheme(preferredTheme || darkQuery);
            })();`
          }}
        />
```

`

The goal is to use the context with "en" or "fr" to render the correct json caracter. At the moment I am stuck at the json part.